# How does "biosdevname" really work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I know the purpose of `"biosdevname"` feature in Linux, but I'm not sure how
exactly it works.

I tested it with Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 14.10 (both 64-bit server editions)
and it looks like they enable it by default - right after system startup my
network interface has a name such as `p4p1` instead of `eth0`, no customization
is needed. As I understood it, in order for `biosdevname` to be enabled, BOTH
of these two conditions must be met:

- a boot option `biosdevname=1` must be passed to a kernel
- `biosdevname` package must be installed

As I already mentioned, both Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 seem to offer `biosdevname`
as a default feature: they come with `biosdevname` package already installed, I
didn't need to modify `grub.cfg` either - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` has no
parameters and my network interface still has a BIOS name (`p*p*`) instead of a
kernel name (`eth*`.)

Later I wanted to restore the old style device naming and that's where the
interesting part begins. I decided to experiment a bit while trying to disable
the `biosdevname` feature. Since it requires `biosdevname` package to work (or
so I read here and there), I assumed removing it would be enough to disable the
feature, so I typed:

```
sudo apt-get purge biosdevname
```

To my surprise, after reboot my network interface was still `p4p1,` so
`biosdevname` clearly still worked even though `biosdevname` package had been
wiped out.

As a next step, I applied appropriate changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` in
order to restore the old name of my network interface (removed entry for `p4p1`
and added entry for `eth0`). As a result, after another reboot, `ifconfig`
reported neither `eth0` nor `p4p1` which was another proof that OS still
understood BIOS names instead of kernel names.

It turned out that I also had to explicitly change GRUB entry to
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=biosdevname=0` and update GRUB to get the expected
result (`biosdevname` disabled and old name of network interface restored).

**My question is**: how could `biosdevname` work without `biosdevname` package? Is
it not required after all? If so, what exactly provides the `biosdevname`
functionality and how does it work?

Comment: You may want to look at the files in /etc/udev/rules.d/ to see if there are rules there to drive network interface naming

Answer (score 10):

The reason biosdevname keeps annoying you even after you uninstall the package, is that it installed itself in the initrd 'initial ramdisk' file as well.

When uninstalling, the /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/biosdevname is removed, but there is no postrm script in the package so update-initramfs is not executed and biosdevname is still present in the /boot/initrd... file used in the first stage of system startup.

You can fully get rid of it like this:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```